# javascript: pass return value in callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

Please help me understand this:

I have an object `self.domainSettings()` which has a `save` method. The `save` returns the result which I want to use in callback function to populate success or error message. I am using following code:

```
self.domainSettings().save(function(data){
    console.log('in here');
    console.log(data);
    console.log('outta here');
 }());

function save(){
  return 'success';
};
```

When I do `console.log(data)` is it guaranteed that the save has finished executing ? Also it says data is undefined because the return value of save is not getting passed to callback function I guess. How do I get that ?

Comment: Why are you immedeately invoking the function you pass to `save`? `}());
`

Comment: I want to get the result of save(as soon as it finishes) and then display that result to user

Comment: what is the implementation code of `self.domainSettings().save` function

Comment: It's given in question. I am just returning 'success'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass callback in `save()` in order to access the result from a callback.

```
function save(fn){
  return fn('success');
};
```